# Conditional hitting time distribution of a Brownian motion

Tags: brownian-motion, stopping-times

This problem cropped up in some research I am doing.  I imagine it is standard, but I cannot seem to find the answer.

Let $W_t$ be a standard Brownian motion.  Suppose there are four values $a < 0 < b$ and $c<d$.  For a given $t > 0$, I want to know the probability that $W_t$ reaches $b$ before reaching $a$ and then after reaching $b$ never falls below $c$ nor exceeds $d$ until time $t$.

Thanks all.

Comment: If it's a standard Brownian motion, then the probabilty that after some point it never falls below $c$ is $0$.

Comment: Sorry, I want to know the prob. it never falls below $c$ or exceeds $d$ until time $t$.

Answer (score 2):

I can't add comments (not enough reputation) so I'm posting this as an answer :

Consider your first problem which is reaching $b$ before $a$. 
Denote $T_a$ and $T_b$ stopping times of $W_t$ reaching a and b and $T=\min(T_a,T_b)$. $W_t$ being a martingale (stopping theorems look wikipedia): 
$\mathbb{E}[W_{\min(t,T)}]=0=\mathbb{E}[a1_{T_a<T_b}]+\mathbb{E}[b1_{T_b\leq T_a}]$
And then :
$$\mathbb{P}[T_a<T_b]=\frac{b}{b-a}$$

You can follow this method to get your results

Comment: That's not quite what I need.  In addition to the probability that $T_b < T_a$, I also need to know the probability that $W_t$ remains within the interval $[c,d]$ (where $c < b < d$) during $[T_b,t]$.

Comment: Agreed, but the result you are looking for can be found in a similar manner. My answer is just the very basic case. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I can compute $P[T_b < T_a]$, $P[T_b < t]$, and $P[\{T_c > t\}\cap \{T_d > t\}]$ but since these events are not independent, I cannot seem to find their joint probability.

Comment: Hint : $W_{t+T_b}-W_{T_b}$ is a standard brownian motion and then reduce to the previous case. (edit : of course you need $c<b<d$ otherwise the result is trivial)

Comment: Sorry for being slow, but I still don't see it.  Define $f(t) = P(T_b \in dt,T_b<T_a)$ and $G_x(s) = P[\min_{0\leq j \leq s} W_j \geq c, \max_{0\leq j \leq s} W_s \leq d | W_0 = x]$.  Then the way I would compute what I'm seeking if I knew $f(t)$ is $\int_0^t f(s)G_b(t-s)ds$.

Comment: Writing integrals is not a good way to go I think. Forget about $b$ : you can work on $W_{t+T_b}-b$.
Then What you are looking for (if I understand correctly) is :
$\mathbb{P}[c\leq W_t\leq d,\forall t\in [0,T]]$. $max_{t\in [0,T]} W_t$ has the same distribution than $|W_T|$. And the minimum is $-\max -W_t$. And $-W_t$ is a standard Brownian motion. Combine all the previous result I think you can get something

Comment: Given T_b, what I'm looking for is $P[c \leq W_s \leq d, \forall s \in [T_b,t]]$ where $t$ is fixed (I think maybe I wasn't clear about this).  The trouble I'm having is that this value depends on $T_b$.

Comment: No it doesn't depend on $T_b$ (except $c<b<d$) because of what I explained. It will reach $b$ with probability 1 and then you start a new BM from $T_b$.